# Swift: check if generic type conforms to protocol

Tags: generics, swift

I have a protocol that I defined like so:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
   ...
}
```

I also have a generic struct:

```
struct MyStruct <T>  {
    ...
}
```

Finally I have a generic function:

```
func myFunc <T> (s: MyStruct<T>) -> T? {
   ...
}
```

I'd like to test inside of the function if the type T conforms to MyProtocol. Essentially I'd like to be able to do (~ pseudocode):

```
let conforms = T.self is MyProtocol
```

But this throws a compiler error:

```
error: cannot downcast from 'T.Type' to non-@objc protocol type 'MyProtocol'
   let conforms = T.self is MyProtocol
                  ~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have also tried variations, like `T.self is MyProtocol.self`, `T is MyProtocol`, and using `==` instead of `is`. So far I haven't gotten anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 102):

I have to say @Alex want to check if `T` type conforms to protocol rather than `s`. And some answerer didn't see clearly.

Check `T` type conforms to protocol like this :

```
if let _ = T.self as? MyProtocol.Type {
    //  T conform MyProtocol
}
```

or

```
if T.self is MyProtocol.Type {
    //  T conform MyProtocol
}
```

Comment: What if MyProtocol is CaseIterable(a Protocol with associated type)? It shows error:  'CaseIterable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

Comment: @zgjie Did you found the answer to your comment ?

Answer (score 87):

A bit late but you can test if something responds to protocol with `as ?` test:

```
if let currentVC = myViewController as? MyCustomProtocol {
    // currentVC responds to the MyCustomProtocol protocol =]
}
```

EDIT: a bit shorter:

```
if let _ = self as? MyProtocol {
    // match
}
```

And using a guard:

```
guard let _ = self as? MyProtocol else {
    // doesn't match
    return
}
```

Comment: This requires an instance of of `T`, but the question asks about generic TYPE. Thus Carlos answer is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787263/1311272

Comment: Carlos Chaguendo answer should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: True, it doesn't answer the question as asked, but it answered _my_ question

Answer (score 40):

The simplest answer is: don’t do that.  Use overloading and constraints instead, and determine everything up-front at compile-time rather than testing stuff dynamically at runtime.  Runtime type checking and compile-time generics are like steak and ice-cream – both are nice but mixing them is a bit weird.

Consider something like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol { }

struct MyStruct <T>  { let val: T }

func myFunc<T: MyProtocol>(s: MyStruct<T>) -> T? {
    return s.val
}

func myFunc<T>(s: MyStruct<T>) -> T? {
    return nil
}

struct S1: MyProtocol { }
struct S2 { }

let m1 = MyStruct(val: S1())
let m2 = MyStruct(val: S2())

myFunc(m1) // returns an instance of S1
myFunc(m2) // returns nil, because S2 doesn't implement MyProtocol
```

The downside being, you can’t establish dynamically if T supports a protocol at runtime:

```
let o: Any = S1()
let m3 = MyStruct(val: o)
myFunc(m3)  // will return nil even though o 
            // does actually implement MyProtocol
```

But, in all honesty, do you really need to do that inside your generic function?  If you’re unsure what actual type something is, the better option may be to figure that out up-front rather than deferring it to later and prodding it inside a generic function to find out.

Comment: +1, good answer. Particularly enjoyed "_Runtime type checking and compile-time generics are like steak and ice-cream – both are nice but mixing them is a bit weird._" 

Comment: Yes…except for the edge cases where overloading and constraints just aren't going to do the job. Consider an extension method that implements a protocol, `JSONEncodable`, that requires `init(json: JSON) throws`. We want `Array` to implement `JSONEncodable`, but only if its elements are also `JSONEncodable`. We can't combine an inheritance clause with constraints, so we must use some kind of type checking inside our implementation of `init`, and perhaps throw an error if the `Element` is not `JSONEncodable`. Sadly, this does not seem to be possible AFAICT.

Comment: I should add that the conundrum above can be solved by using an intermediate type as a thunk, but that's a pretty inelegant solution.

Comment: @GregoryHigley that should be possible now with conditional conformance in Swift 4.1 (https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/)

Comment: It's cool how you can construct `MyStruct` with or without the hint like `<Type>` and it can tell what to do. For others trying the code out, Swift 4 needs a `_` on the first constructor argument

Answer (score 24):

let conforms = T.self is MyProtocol.Type

Comment: This is the best answer because it answers the original question "how to do: `let conforms = T.self is MyProtocol`".

Comment: Agreed, best answer of the question!

Comment: doesn't work with associatedType protocols (generic)

Answer (score 12):

you can also leverage swift's [switch case pattern matching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID425), if you want to handle multiple cases of type `T`:

```
func myFunc<T>(s: MyStruct<T>) -> T? {
    switch s {
    case let sType as MyProtocol:
        // do MyProtocol specific stuff here, using sType
    default:
        //this does not conform to MyProtocol
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question as it's testing in an instance conforms to the protocol rather than the type directly.

Answer (score 6):

You need declare protocol as `@objc`:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    ...
}
```

From Apple's "The Swift Programming Language" book:

> You can check for protocol conformance only if your protocol is marked with the @objc attribute, as seen for the HasArea protocol above. This attribute indicates that the protocol should be exposed to Objective-C code and is described in Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C. Even if you are not interoperating with Objective-C, you need to mark your protocols with the @objc attribute if you want to be able to check for protocol conformance.
>
> Note also that @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes, and not by structures or enumerations. If you mark your protocol as @objc in order to check for conformance, you will be able to apply that protocol only to class types.

Comment: Even with this, I still get the same error. `@objc protocol MyProtocol {}

struct MyStruct <T>  {}

func myFunc <T> (s: MyStruct<T>) -> T? {
    let conforms = T.self is MyProtocol
}`

Comment: @Alex, you need to construct instance of T type before you can check to protocol conformance (as I know)
If you need than type T must be only of type than conforms to MyProtocol, you can specify it: `func myFunc<T: MyProtocol>(...) -> T?`

Answer (score 6):

For test cases I check conformance like this:

```
let conforms: Bool = (Controller.self as Any) is Protocol.Type
```

Answer (score -4):

A modern answer will be like this: (Swift 5.1)

```
func myFunc < T: MyProtocol> (s: MyStruct<T>) -> T? {    ... }
```

Comment: ?? How does that answer the question?