# How to extend a protocol that satisfies Multiple Constraints - Swift 2.0

Tags: protocols, swift2

I am trying to provide a default implementation of protocol so it can satisfy multiple constraints from other protocols.

Given the following protocols:

```
public protocol Creature {
    var name: String { get }
    var canMove: Bool { get }
}

public protocol Animal: Creature {}

public protocol Moveable {
    var movingSpeed: Double { get set }
}

public protocol Agend {
    var aged: Int { get }
}
```

I'm able to extend using a single condition on `Self`:

```
// all animals can move
extension Moveable where Self: Animal {
    public var canMove: Bool { return true }
}
```

But how do I set constraints to provide a default `Moveable` implementation for types that conform to both `Animal` and `Aged` protocols? Something like below? Or is there some "add" "or" option for the where clause?

```
// Pseudocode which doesn't work
extension Moveable where Self: Animal && Self: Aged {
    public var canMove: Bool { return true }
}
```

Comment: By the way, to see the final code sample that I wrote, visit : http://audreyli.me/2015/06/29/strategy-design-pattern-updated-using-protocol-extension-in-swift-2-0/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You could use a [protocol composition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html):

```
extension Moveable where Self: protocol<Animal, Aged> {
    // ... 
}
```

Or just add the conformances one after the other:

```
extension Moveable where Self: Animal, Self: Aged {
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: This is great for when it must conform to both, but what about if you'd want to check for conformance for one OR the other? Something along the lines of: extension Movable where Self: protocol<Animal || Aged>...

Comment: @Dylan, instead of checking conformance, this syntax is used to say a type conforms to a protocol. To check conformance to a protocol take a look at AirspeedVelocity's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124684/swift-check-if-generic-type-conforms-to-protocol

Comment: Apparently there is a new syntax, and the protocol<..> has been removed. Use the & syntax in Swift 4.

Answer (score 42):

As of the time of this post, the answer is using `protocol<Animal, Aged>`.

In Swift 3.0, `protocol<Animal, Aged>` is deprecated.

The correct usage in Swift 3.0 is:

```
extension Moveable where Self: Animal & Aged {
    // ... 
}
```

You can also combine the protocols with a `typealias`. This is useful when you are using a combination of protocols in multiple places (avoids duplication and promotes maintainability).

```
typealias AgedAnimal = Aged & Animal
extension Moveable where Self: AgedAnimal {
    // ... 
}
```

Comment: I know some time has passed, but typealias types won't come across in Objective-C (e.g., for checking protocol conformance). I ended up doing this: `@objc public protocol AgedAnimal: Aged, Animal {} `

Answer (score 2):

Since Swift 3 you can use `typealias` to create types that conform to multiple protocols:

```
typealias AgedAnimal = Animal & Aged
```

So your code would become:

```
extension Moveable where Self: AgedAnimal {
    // ...
}
```

Or like this:

```
typealias Live = Aged & Moveable

extension Animal where Self: Live {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the protocol become reference type

```
extension Moveable: AnyObject {}
```